# Hilbert's 90 Theorem proof clarification (Milne's Étale Cohomology)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, etale-cohomology

So I'm reading Milne's Étale Cohomology and stuck in trouble to understand the proof of Proposition 4.9 Hilbert's Theorem 90), from §4; page 124:

The canonical maps $$ H^1(X_{Zar},  \mathcal{O}_X^*) \to H^1(X_{et},  \mathbb{G}_m)  \to H^1(X_{fl},  \mathbb{G}_m)$$ are isomorphisms. $X_x$ with $x = Zar,et, fl$ denotes the "topology" of $X$. the proof only shows $ H^1(X_{Zar},  \mathcal{O}_X^*) \to H^1(X_{fl})$. according to the proof by Theroem 1.18 it suffice to show that $R^1f_*\mathbb{G}_m=0$. for this, let $U$ be a Zariski open subset of $X$ and we must show that $H^1(U_{fl},  \mathbb{G}_m)$ becomes zero. if we consider a Zariski open affine cover of $U$ by a family $U_i$, we can assume that $U$ is affine, since we can the $U_i$ choose to be affine, i.e. $U=spec(A)$. this reduction is clearly can be done with sheaf axiom in mind.

The step that confuses me that futhermore is told that is can be also be assumed that $A$ is a **local** ring. why this assumption can be done here?

Comment: You can just show the stalks are zero, yeah?

Comment: yes, you are right, checking the vanishing on stalks, would also immerdiately imply $R^1f_*\mathbb{G}_m=0$. my concern is why does it suffice to check, that $H^1(spec(A)_{fl},  \mathbb{G}_m)=0$ for affine & local $A$, to conclude, that $R^1f_*\mathbb{G}_m$ vanish on stalks? assume $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime of (now not more local) $spec(A)$ and we consider the localization $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$: suppose we know that $H^1((spec(A_{\mathfrak{p}})_{fl},  \mathbb{G}_m)=0$ for all primes

Comment: of $A$. the stalk at $\mathfrak{p}$ is by definition $(R^1f_*\mathbb{G}_m)_{\mathfrak{p}}= R^1f_*\mathbb{G}_m \otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and the important question is why $R^1f_*\mathbb{G}_m \otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p}}=H^1((spec(A_{\mathfrak{p}})_{fl},  \mathbb{G}_m)$ or in other works why $H^1((-)_{fl},  \mathbb{G}_m)$ respects localizations, i.e. why $H^1((spec(A_{\mathfrak{p}})_{fl},  \mathbb{G}_m)= H^1(spec(A)_{fl},  \mathbb{G}_m) \otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p}}$? I think that this is exaclty the book uses implicitly at this point

Comment: Does this help: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03Q4? Sorry I'm on my phone, I can dialogue more usefully tomorrow.

Comment: Oops, I meant this: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09YQ